# Set HTML content of GTK Webkit.Webview?

Tags: python, webview, gtk

I'm developing a python GTK application that uses the `WebKit.WebView`, and I can open web pages fine, however, I'd like to just set HTML rather than reading it from a website or file? How can I do this? Should I save the HTML to a file and then read it in?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the [`load_bytes()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit2-4.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit2.WebView.load_bytes) method?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at PyQt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml('<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>')
view.show()
```